# Comparing 2 count columns with case

Tags: sql-server, query, count, syntax, case

I have 2 tables, size and cost. My query does a count with a greater than comparison of cost and counts different sizes.

table1: size u  
table2: cred t

Here is my query:  
select u.size as size  
,count(u.size) * .4 as "40% of size"  
,count(case when (t.cred * 12) > (t.inc *.3) then 1 end) as "30% cost"  
from cred t  
join size u on t.id = u.id  
group by u.size

The result is as follows:

| Size | 40% of size | 30% cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 75.6 | 50 |
| 1 | 470.4 | 160 |
| 2 | 414.8 | 114 |
| 3 | 202.8 | 59 |
| 4 | 40 | 21 |
| 5 | 8.8 | 9 |
| 6 | 0.4 | 1 |

I want the query to show a 'Y' if the cost column is larger than the size column and a 'N' if it is smaller. Here would be the result I'm looking for:

| Size | 40% of size | 30% cost | Y/N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 75.6 | 50 | N |
| 1 | 470.4 | 160 | N |
| 2 | 414.8 | 114 | N |
| 3 | 202.8 | 59 | N |
| 4 | 40 | 21 | N |
| 5 | 8.8 | 9 | Y |
| 6 | 0.4 | 1 | Y |

Is there a way to show this? I tried to use the following, but I get this:  Boolean value cannot be operated with non-Boolean value.

,case when ((t.cred * 12) > (t.inc * .3)) > (count(u.size) * .4) then 'Y' else 'N' end as "Y/N"  
Not sure if I need to do a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery or cte to make it more readable, but you don't have to.  Version with subquery :

```
select a.* , 
case  
  when [30% cost]>[40% of size] then 'Y' 
  else 'N' 
end as [Y/N]
from 
( 
  select u.size as size
  ,count(u.size) * .4 as "40% of size"
  ,count(case when (t.cred * 12) > (t.inc *.3) then 1 end) as "30% cost"
  from cred t
  join size u on t.id = u.id
  group by u.size
)a
```

Without subquery

```
      select u.size as size
      ,count(u.size) * .4 as "40% of size"
      ,count(case when (t.cred * 12) > (t.inc *.3) then 1 end) as "30% cost"
      case 
        when count(case when (t.cred * 12) > (t.inc *.3) then 1 end) > count(u.size) * .4 then 'Y'
        else 'N' 
      end as [Y/N]
      from cred t
      join size u on t.id = u.id
      group by u.size
```

Comment: Brilliant @alex07!! Thanks!!! Looks like I missed a "count" and also misplaced parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably use a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get your desired result.

something like this:

```
with cte as(
select u.size as size
,count(u.size) * .4 as "40% of size"
,count(case when (t.cred * 12) > (t.inc *.3) then 1 end) as "30% cost"
from cred t
join size u on t.id = u.id
group by u.size )


select Size,[40% of size],[30% cost],
case when [30% cost]>[40% of size] then 'Y'
    Else 'N' as [Y/N]
from cte;
```

Comment: I tried to use a cte, but the error keeps coming back: Your statement must start with CREATE, DROP, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, ALTER, EXECUTE, DELETE, GRANT, REVOKE, BEGIN, COMMIT, ROLLBACK, SAVEPOINT, SET, DEBUG or a script statement. I'm assuming that I would need to use a subquery?

Comment: if you edit your post to include tables schema and sample data, i might be able to provide a better answer